# Matlab: Matrix with all combinations of 0s and 1s with at least k 1s in each row

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations, combinatorics

So I choose a row length, say n, and each row will only contain 0s and 1s and will have at least k 1s. I would like to have a matrix with all possible combinations in Matlab.

For example, n=3 k=2:

1 1 0

1 0 1

0 1 1

1 1 1

Comment: Have you tried something yet? I doubt there is such primitive in Matlab, so you must write a script, and therefore provide a sample of what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dec2bin` to create all of the bit patterns and then keep only the patterns with the correct number of `1`s:

```
n = 3; k = 2;
allCombs = dec2bin( (2^k-1):(2^n-1) ) - '0'; % use -'0' to convert to integers
outCombs = allCombs(sum(allCombs, 2) >= k, :);

outCombs =

   0   1   1
   1   0   1
   1   1   0
   1   1   1
```

Comment: Brilliant._____